# bootstrap form-control and grid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

What am I missing here?

Not only are my labels on top of my input field but the input field is as wide as the page.

[UPDATED with improved code]

```
<form class="form-horizontal" #scheduleWorkForm="ngForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="averageHoursWorkedPerWeek">{{ 'RequestTimeOff.AvgHoursWorked' | translate }}</label>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <input class="form-control col-md-5" type="number" [numRange]="{ min: 1, max: 140 }" [(ngModel)]="incident.schedule.averageHoursWorkedPerWeek" name="averageHoursWorkedPerWeek" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

When I examine the rendered CSS, I see that div.form-control width is set explicitly to 100%, but div.col-md-x has no width specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not nesting the `.form-control` properly; instead of combining that class with the Bootstrap Grid, you need to nest it within a Grid wrapper:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" #scheduleWorkForm="ngForm">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="averageHoursWorkedPerWeek">{{ 'RequestTimeOff.AvgHoursWorked' | translate }}</label>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <input class="form-control col-md-5" type="number" [numRange]="{ min: 1, max: 140 }" [(ngModel)]="incident.schedule.averageHoursWorkedPerWeek" name="averageHoursWorkedPerWeek" />
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see more examples of how `.form-horizontal` interacts with `.form-group` and `.form-control` here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms-horizontal

Comment: I've updated the original to reflect your response. Same effect.  (Also, I'm following the docs, but can't seem to see what I'm doing wrong.)

Comment: Oh for Pete's sake. Rebuilding the app did the trick. I don't know how it was updating the markup but not reflecting the changes on-screen. I was using the inspector and seeing my markup changes in real-time.

Comment: Been there! Can't tell you how many CSS issues I've had because my changes were never reflected when compiling!